# Cannot save or create db in device

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to save my data directly into the device folder that i had created but not in the data/data/packagename.

I had tried before, it successed to created a db file and i can update the data. But now i'm using the same code, it return error 14, could not open database.

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator + FILE_DIR
            + File.separator + "Database"
            + File.separator + DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      this.context = context;
      DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
                 File.separator + FILE_DIR + 
                 File.separator + "Database" + 
                 File.separator;
      myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the folder the database resides in must have write permissions, as well as the actual database file.

If you're making any update operation such as insert, delete, update... You'll need that permissions

Comment: I mean you must have permission on your file system to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FILE_DIR + File.separator + "Database" + File.separator + DB_NAME